# How to avoid bind/lambda in functional components event handlers?

Tags: reactjs

I have a functional component :

```
function MyComponent(props){
    return <button onClick={() => props.onClick(props.count + 1)}> Click me </button>
}
```

Now, a lot of online resources suggest to not use this way of attaching the event listener (when it needs some params to be passed), as it needs to create new functions on every render. 
For class based components, they suggest to extract another component out of this and pass the param as prop to that component. But how are we supposed to rewrite these bindings in functional components?

One such resource: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md

Answer (score 4):

In general, I wouldn't worry about this pattern. If you look at the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#is-it-ok-to-use-arrow-functions-in-render-methods), the advice given is

> it OK to use arrow functions in render methods?
>   Generally speaking, yes, it is OK, and it is often the easiest way to pass parameters to callback functions.
>   If you do have performance issues, by all means, optimize!

So if you don't actually notice a problem with creating a new function every render, it's not something to worry about. It's pretty rare that it will ever be noticeable.

If you do find yourself in a situation where you're sure you need to prevent a new function each render, I would probably just convert it to a class component.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to satisfy eslint rule you could try something like this

```
function MyComponent(props){
         const handleClick = props => props.onClick(props.count + 1);  
         return <button onClick={handleClick}> Click me </button>
    }
```

But you could also change your stateless component to class based